# remote image properties using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i am trying to get remote image width/height. I am developing a link sharing module something like when you paste a link on facebook, you can see title, description and images.

So i tried using php getimagesize to get image width/height its very slow.

So i am thinking of using jquery solution to get remote image width/height so that i can filter image width less then 100px.

I am new in jquery/javascript

I tried something like

```
var img = $('#imageID');
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
$('#info').html(width+'.. height: '+height);
```

Its not working and return undefined .. height: undefined

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how far have you gone with this link sharing code. im trying to find a jquery plugin out there that can do this....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://your.url.here/image.png';
img.onload = function() {
  $('#info').text('height: ' + img.height + ' width: ' + img.width);
};
```

This approach would let you get the image info without having to have an `<img>` tag at all. Now, perhaps you *want* the image to be on the page, so you'd do what @patrick suggests in that case.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. If the intention was to get the info without (necessarily) inserting into the DOM, this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the width and height of the image in the client side, you can use jQuery's [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width) and [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) methods.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aeBWQ/

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var img = $('#imageID');
    var width = img.width();
    var height = img.height();
    $('#info').html(width+'.. height: '+height); 
});
```

Doing `$(window).load()` will ensure that the images are loaded before getting the height/width.