# jQuery code to find the image width and height using image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

In our site we are accessing our images or the image source is like

```
<img src="image_manage.php&type=resize&id=12" />
```

My issue is, to get the image height and width using this source in jquery.
I write a code  to get the width and height

```
photograf = new Image();
photograf.src = '/image_manage.php&type=resize&id=12';
var width = photograf.width;
var height = photograf.height;
```

But I got the value zero for both height and width what is the issue?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595113/remote-image-properties-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var oImage = new Image();

oImage.onload = function(){
    this.width// width of loaded image
}

oImage.src = '/path/to/image.gif';
```

Or something like that is better:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
width = $("img").attr('width');    //can also $("img").width();
hight = $("img").attr('height');   //can also $("img").height();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wait for the image to load in order to detect it's size.

```
$("#imgElement").attr('src',photograf.src).load(function(){
    var w = $("imgElement").width();
    var h = $("imgElement").height();
});
```

Here I am setting the `src` parameter of the image and using jQuery's `load()` function to detect when the image has been successfully loaded.

Reference -

- [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) functions:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $width = jQuery("img").width();
    var $height = jQuery("img").height();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
width = $("img").prop('width');   
hight = $("img").prop('height');
```

Dont forget to put js code in `load` or `document ready` events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $('img').prop('height');
    var width= $('img').prop('width');
    alert('Height :'+height+' AND '+'width :'+width);
});
```

here is the running example
**Example**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Azsxg/)

Answer (score 0):

The image isn't loaded yet when you ask for its size. The onLoad method is helpful for this purpose.

```
photograf = new Image();
photograf.src = '/image_manage.php&type=resize&id=12';
photograf.onLoad = function(){ 
    var width = this.width; 
    var height = this.height; 
};
```